# Using call with variable expansion when string contains % (percent sign) in a batchfile

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping, call

I am having a problem using call to pass values represented by variables when the expanded variable contains a "%" in the string. I know that on an individual basis I would just use an escape character to (presumably %%) but these variables come from folder names that other people created and change based upon their whims.

I have tried a number of different attempts at fixes and some diagnostics (as shown below).

A sample of the code: (setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion)

```
:findMostRecentFiles
        REM call :findMostRecentFiles %productFile% %pathPrefix% %resultFile%
        break>%~3
        For /f "tokens=* delims=" %%g In (%~1) Do (
            set fullFolderPath=%~2\%%g\
            Echo !fullFolderPath!
            Echo !fullFolderPath!>>%~3
            Echo Calling findMostRecentFile:
            call :findMostRecentFile "!fullFolderPath!" "%~3"
        )
    goto :eof

:findMostRecentFile
    :: REM call :findMostRecentFile "!fullFolderPath!" %~3 
    :: Echo %~1
    Echo Checking FullFolderPath (no quotes): %~1
    Echo Checking FullFolderPath (quotes): "%~1"
    Echo Checking resultFile: %~2
    Echo About to push: "%~1"
    Pushd "%~1"
    cd

    popd
goto :eof
```

Portion of Result:

```
set fullFolderPath=S:\QA\BA 25% TMAH\
 Echo !fullFolderPath!
 Echo !fullFolderPath! 1>>C:\Users\M2\Desktop\ProductList_Recent.txt
 Echo Calling findMostRecentFile:
 call :findMostRecentFile "!fullFolderPath!" "C:\Users\M2\Desktop\ProductList_Recent.txt"

)
S:\QA\BA 25% TMAH\
Calling findMostRecentFile:

S:\QA>Echo Checking FullFolderPath (no quotes): S:\QA\BA 25\Users\M2\Desktop\Produc
tList_Recent.txt
Checking FullFolderPath (no quotes): S:\QA\BA 25\Users\M2\Desktop\ProductList_Recent.txt

S:\QA>Echo Checking FullFolderPath (quotes): "S:\QA\BA 25\Users\M2\Desktop\ProductL
ist_Recent.txt"
Checking FullFolderPath (quotes): "S:\QA\BA 25\Users\M2\Desktop\ProductList_Recent.
txt"

S:\QA>Echo Checking resultFile:
Checking resultFile:

S:\QA>Echo About to push: "S:\QA\BA 25\Users\M2\Desktop\ProductList_Recent.tx
t"
About to push: "S:\QA\BA 25\Users\M2\Desktop\ProductList_Recent.txt"

S:\QA>Pushd "S:\QA\BA 25\Users\M2\Desktop\ProductList_Recent.txt"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

It is treating the expanded variables in a way that I didn't expect (though obviously the correct behavior for what i wrote) and I don't know how to make it so that when the *fullFolderPath* contains a "%" that it is passed as its own value rather than concatenating it with the other variables passed to call.

Any help or explanations would be great!

Comment: A possible work-around is to pass the variable name to the subroutine rather than the value; for example: `call :SUB VAR`, and in the subroutine use `!%~1!` to expand the value of `VAR`...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I didn't realize that you can pass variables to call in that fashion using a batch-file. I had though you had to pass the value, not the reference (if that is the correct terminology?). Can you comment on if this work-around was possible because I was not restricting my functions to being local (i.e. wrapping the code body in setlocal/endlocal)?

Comment: This would work even if you place `setlocal`/`endlocal` around your function, because `setlocal` does not destroy any variable values; however, if you change the value of the variable passed to the function (`!%~1!`), you need to apply the change *after* `endlocal` to not lose it, which can be a bit tricky; one way is to write `endlocal & set %~1=%VAR%` (see also [this external link](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible work-around is to pass the variable name to the subroutine rather than the value, and apply delayed expansion there.

Here is the modified code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:findMostRecentFiles
        REM call :findMostRecentFiles %productFile% %pathPrefix% %resultFile%
        break>%~3
        For /f "tokens=* delims=" %%g In (%~1) Do (
            set fullFolderPath=%~2\%%g\
            Echo !fullFolderPath!
            Echo !fullFolderPath!>>%~3
            Echo Calling findMostRecentFile:
            call :findMostRecentFile fullFolderPath "%~3"
        )
    goto :eof

:findMostRecentFile
    :: REM call :findMostRecentFile fullFolderPath %~3 
    :: Echo !%~1!
    Echo Checking FullFolderPath (no quotes): !%~1!
    Echo Checking FullFolderPath (quotes): "!%~1!"
    Echo Checking resultFile: %~2
    Echo About to push: "!%~1!"
    Pushd "!%~1!"
    cd

    popd
goto :eof
```

---

The problem in your code is the fact that subroutine argument expansion happens quite early in the command interpreter, even before immediate (`%`) variable expansion. If a single `%` character occurs in an argument, it disappears. If there are two `%` characters, everything in between is treated like a variable name; if there is actually a variable with that name, it is expanded to its value; if not, the entire expression including the surrounding  `%` signs is removed. There are even worse cases when colons and/or equal-to signs appear in between the percent signs, because such denote sub-string substitution syntax (see `set /?` for details).

Of course you could simply substitute each `%` sign by `%%` in your code, like `call :findMostRecentFile "!fullFolderPath:%%=%%%%!" "%~3"` (each `%` is doubled as `%%` make one literal `%`). But there are more characters that could cause trouble, like the exclamation mark `!` since you have delayed variable expansion enabled (so the same issues as for `%` apply), or `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, which could also appear within paths, and also `<`, `>`, `|` and `"`. Avoiding argument expansion (`%1`) and also immediate variable expansion (`%%`) by using delayed expansion (`!!`) prevents the script from running into all those problems.